# How to remove a row in a joined table?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a table called `LocalEventSessions`. It has 2 columns, `localevent_id` and `session_id`.

In my `LocalEventSessionRepository` I have this code:

```
List<LocalEventSession> findAllByLocalEventSessionId_localEventId(Integer id);
```

This returns a list of all sessions belonging to a LocalEvent. This is used to display the sessions.

I would like to remove a session relation to a localevent. So I wrote this:

```
Integer deleteByLocalEventIdAndSessionId(@Param("localevent_id") Integer lid, @Param("session_id") Integer sid);
```

I expect this to delete record in the `LocalEventSession` table based on the `localevent_id` and `session_id`. I can compile the code with no problem but when I deploy it with Wildfly I receive several errors. At the end of stacktrace it shows that Wildfly is unable to locate the localEventId attribute.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [localEventId] on this ManagedType [net.atos.eventsite.jar.LocalEventSession]"},
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./beheerback"],
"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
```

If I deploy the code without the `deleteBy` method declaration it compiles and deploys without any problem.

Comment: To remove a row of a join table, you simply remove the element from the collection that is mapped using that join table: `course.students.remove(student)`

Comment: @JBNizet Using .remove on the arraylist I was able te remove a object from the array, but not from the table. What I had to do was find the correct object and used the .delete() method from Spring to remove it from the db. Like so `localEventSessionRepository.delete(j);` J is the object returned by a for loop that compares the localevent_id with the sessions_id.

Comment: It's looking for `localEventId` but you seem to have `localevent_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the advice of JB Nizet I created a arraylist with all localeventid's and sessionid's objects. Then with a for loop I can search for the correct object like so:

```
for (LocalEventSession j : deleteItem) {
    if (j.getSessionId() == sessionId) { 
        localEventSessionRepository.delete(j);          
    }
}
```

And then use the delete() method from Spring to remove the record from the table.